# How to sniff Java applet HTTP traffic on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, http, networking, utilities

Are there any utilities/browser plugins to sniff java applet http traffic except for `tcpdump`? I'd like to have well-structured representation.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) - it has very structured data view, and great query capabilities.

Comment: I was trying to install Wireshark on my 10.8.2. It requires XQuartz to start. I installed XQuartz but id doesn't work - system failure on startup.

Comment: I don't have a Mac so can't test it :( googling a bit shows that people have managed to install it on Mountain Lion - you ll have to bug around with installation obviously but I strongly recommend it, it is the best that I have ever seen.